# Can a Sorcerer heighten a granted spell?

Tags: spells, sorcerer, pathfinder-2e

You only add granted spells to your repertoire<sup>1</sup>, and there the levels are fixed. For example, Demonic sorcerers have the divine spell list, but get Slow as a granted spell.
**Does it mean you cannot heighten them?**
(Unless of course you make them signature spells)

---

1. not your spell list, like a Cleric

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You can learn these spells on higher levels

The "Spell Repertoire" feature for sorcerers includes the following line:

> When you add spells, you might select a higher-level version of a spell you already know so that you can cast a heightened version of that spell.

See [Sorcerer (Archives of Nethys)](http://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=11)

As you already know the spells granted by your bloodline, you can simply learn a higher level version of these spells each time you gain a level, even though they are not on your spell list.

Now, there is a "might" in that rules excerpt, which could be interpreted as advice for the player and not as a rule. While I disagree with that interpretation (simply because I have not seen the game give advice to players in that manner anywhere else in rules blocks like this one), I decided to look at what the german version of the basic rules that I have at home has to say:

> Wenn du Zauber hinzufügst, kannst du eine höhergradige Version eines dir bereits verfügbaren Zaubers hinzufügen, so dass du ihn nun mit erhöhtem Grad wirken kannst

(German Grundregelwerk, Page 205)

In english, this would pretty much say the following:

> If you add spells, you can add a version of a higher spell level of a spell **available to you**, so that you can cast it with a higher level

Now, the "available to you" is sadly still up to interpretation, but at least the german version supports my interpretation that "you *might* select [...]" is meant to be a rule that allows you to do just that, and not just advice for a player.

Comment: "bereits" implies already available.

Comment: Yeah, which the spell granted by your bloodline is. It is available to you (available to cast/available in your repertoire)

Comment: "When you get spell slots of 2nd level and higher, you can fill those slots with stronger versions of lower-level spells. This increases the spell's level to match the spell slot. " Maybe this would add better support.

Comment: I don't think so, this question is about learning the spells, not filling the slots, those are two very different things.

Comment: Yes, the idea was to make the distinction clear, but maybe that is too convoluted? (to explain what heightening spells is)

Comment: I would argue that "available to you" would mean spells you are allowed to learn, not spells you are able to cast. Unfortunately, I don't know German, so I'm not sure if there would be a linguistic distinction to better specify.

Comment: The german version explicitly uses "verfügbar", which means "available", but it uses "Zugang" (Access) for the specific mechanic of spells you are allowed to learn, weapons you are allowed to buy (e.g. at character creation) and so on.

Comment: Doesn't that support against your point? Wouldn't they say "you have" *Zugang* "to higher-level versions of spells you already know"?

Comment: Not in my opinion, because having access to something is a specific rules thing, used in specific contexts, and while that context does include spells, it does not include the specific level of the spell.

Comment: It's another tenuous point, but you can further support this with another "it doesn't really work but suggests it should" from [Traditions and School](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=260). "[...] In some cases, such as when a cleric gains spells from their deity or when a sorcerer gets spells from their bloodline, you might be able to cast spells from a different spell list. In these cases, the spell uses your magic tradition, not the list the spell normally comes from. When you cast a spell, add your tradition’s trait to the spell."

Comment: It doesn't *say* that the spells are part of your Tradition but it *does* correlate Bloodline to Deity spells and kind of suggest they "are" part of your Tradition, which is almost interchangeable with Spell List.

Comment: tbh I think that too much speculation and such only muddies the water here. In my opinion, the first rules text I quoted is already enough to prove (to me without real doubt) that you can learn higher level versions of these spells. Yes, the wording could also be interpreted simply as advice for the player, but 2e does not give such advice anywhere else in rule text (that I have seen), and I see no reason why it should do that in this specific case. Everything on top of that frankly (to me) simply comes across as grasping at straws, which is in my opinion not necessary in this case :D

Answer (score 3):

### Ignoring RAW for a moment...

As I noted in the comments for my [Answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/188181/28326) that sparked this question, I find the Rules as Written to be lacking leading to an *extremely silly* conclusion and recommend all GM's make a common sense ruling that granted spells are on sorcerer's spell lists. Besides avoiding complications such as technically not being able to Heighten and questions about using wands/scrolls/staves of the spell, it also brings the features in line with similar abilities such as [Clerics](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=5)' Deity spells.

> Your deity also adds spells to your spell list.

I firmly believe this was *intended* (although I don't know of any developer commentary) and hope that the language of Bloodline is updated to explicitly indicate this. Some rules seem to suggest the intention, notably Spells' [Tradition and School](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=260) section, which includes:

> Your class determines which tradition of magic your spells use. In some cases, such as when a cleric gains spells from their deity or when a sorcerer gets spells from their bloodline, you might be able to cast spells from a different spell list. In these cases, the spell uses your magic tradition, not the list the spell normally comes from. When you cast a spell, add your tradition’s trait to the spell.

Most importantly, this ties Bloodline granted spells to Deity granted spells in a tangible way. It also suggests that the spells are "part of" the Tradition for that spellcaster (although, again, it doesn't say such explicitly).

### RAW: Bloodline granted spells are not on your Spell List

You can only learn spells that are on your spell list and only cast spells from your Repertoire. Because the phrase "are added to your spell list" and similar are missing from granted spells, they do not qualify for learning (although they can be cast because they're in your Repertoire).

Bloodline gives you

> ...the type of spells you cast and the spell list you choose them from, **additional spells you learn**, and additional trained skills.

Sorcerer Spellcasting contains details like

> You must know spells to cast them, and you **learn them via the spell repertoire** class feature. [Heightening Spells] You must have a spell **in your spell repertoire** at the level you want to cast in order to heighten it to that level.

and the Spell Repertoire class feature does not mention choosing your Bloodline's granted spells outside of the level they are gained at.

> At 1st level, you learn two 1st-level spells of your choice and four cantrips of your choice, as well as an additional spell and cantrip from your bloodline. **You choose these from the common spells from the tradition corresponding to your bloodline, or from other spells from that tradition** to which you have access. [...] When you gain access to a new level of spells, your first new spell is always the spell granted by your bloodline, but **you can choose the other spells.**

---

It specifically notes about choosing the same spell multiple times in order to Heighten it:

> When you add spells, **you might select a higher-level version of a spell you already know so that** you can cast a heightened version of that spell.

This *in no way* gives permission for you to choose spells you already have in your Repertoire, only suggests why you might want to (*so that* you can cast a heightened version). They distinctly did not use words such as "may" or the less formal "can" and definitely not the common game terms "are allowed to"/"have Access to" as used previously in the Class Feature "You choose these from the common spells [...] other spells from that tardition to which you have access".

---

You *can* choose them as Signature Spells because it doesn't restrict you by spell list.

> For each spell level you have access to, choose one spell of that level to be a signature spell. You don’t need to learn heightened versions of signature spells separately; instead, you can heighten these spells freely.

Comment: What about the line "When you add spells, you might select a higher-level version of a spell you already know so that you can cast a heightened version of that spell." that is included in the description of the "Spell Repertoire" Feature?

Comment: @Patta yes, I saw your answer. I'm posting an alternative one so the community has options to vote toward. To answer your question, though, that describes *why you* **"might"** *want* to choose a spell more than once, and does not say "You can choose to learn a higher-level version of a spell you know..." or similar.

Comment: I never interpreted the "might" as advice for the player, that is why I commented on your answer, thinking that what I quoted would mean that your answer is simply false. I see now that this is not the case. Well, then there is only one thing left for me to do: check my german version of the game for what it says :D

Comment: Maybe if I start with my conclusion, people wont downvote me for being technically correct (the best kind of correct)?

Answer (score 0):

#### It is not needed since they are automatically heightened.

[From Bloodline spells section](https://2e.aonprd.com/Bloodlines.aspx)

> Your bloodline grants you bloodline spells, special spells unique to your lineage. **Bloodline spells are a type of focus spell.** [...] Unlike other characters, you don't need to do anything specific to Refocus, as the power flowing through your veins naturally replenishes your focus pool.
> **Focus spells are automatically heightened to half your level rounded up.** Focus spells don't require spell slots, nor can you cast them using spell slots. Taking feats can give you more focus spells and increase the size of your focus pool, though your focus pool can never hold more than 3 points.

So yes, if you for example receive a ***spell X*** as a bloodline spell, that spell will be automatically heightened.

Comment: There is a bloodline that grants you "heal" as a focus spell? I can't find one that does on Archives of Nethys, though. Or was that just an example of the top of your head?

Comment: sorry, left out "granted" from the question, clarified now

Comment: @Patta It is just an example of the top of my head since heal spell is a spell you usually heighten to heal more. I will edit to clarify, thank you.

Comment: I believe the question was edited out from under this answer, yes? @Mouza - this answer was originally addressing "bloodline spells" which are focus spells, and not the spells granted by your bloodline, right?

Comment: @ESCE Oh...apparently yes it seems the question is completely different now from the original one. Not the best behaviour in my opinion...anyway i will delete my answer asap. Thank you for noticing me!